# Exporting runnable jar with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I know this has been asked for a nuber of times, but thoose answers didn't help

I have a project, it has two packages (core and images) and three prperties files. Core contains six classes and images a single gif images.

I want to use Eclipse to export my project to a runnable jar in a way that a single jar file is created that can run regardless of it's location.

I tried with export->runnable jar and I tried with fat jar exporter (which worked, but only in folder), but it just won't work.

Can anyone tell me what settings should I use during the eclipse export?

Comment: Why did export->runnable jar not work? What was the error you received?

Comment: When I ran it, it didn't do anything (my program has GUI, and I tried running it with both java.exe and javaw.exe)

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got a problem reading your properties files and/or *.gif images.  Have you tried adding print statements and then running from the command line to try to figure out where things are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Lawry was correct, my properties files were not being accessed properly, and since they were loaded before the GUI appeared, program failed upon startup without showing anything...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your choosing the wrong main method for your jar.

Does your application have multiple launch configurations?

Make sure to choose the right launch configuration when you export it.